# How to save an image to a subdomain from the root domain?

Tags: php, image, save

I need to upload an image and save it to a subdomain. Is it possible to do that if the upload script is in the root?
This are the file paths:
Upload script:

```
https://www.example.com/upload/save.php
```

Image Storing:

```
http://imgs.example.com/temp
```

My PHP:

```
 $tempFolder = 'tempimages/';
    $fh = fopen($tempFolder.$filename, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = base64_decode($base64image);
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the structure for a website with subdomain is this one:

- `/home/xxxx/public_html/[subdomain]/`
  So if it's like this, and your script is in `upload/`, you could write to `../imgs/`. It'd go one directory up to the main `public_html`, and then enter the `imgs` subdomain folder.

It could be like this too:

- `/home/xxxx/[subdomain]/`
  If it's like that, you should write to `../../imgs`. That goes one directory up to `public_html`, then once again to the parent of `public_html`, and then to its sibling `imgs`.

Please note that, depeding on your configuration, the subdomain folder can be **anywhere**. These 2 examples are the most common ones.

Comment: I can't figure out the correct path to the subdomain. My structure is like this: `/www/htdocs/w0000000/` (I'm on shared hosting) Any ideas?

Comment: You should go to your host's control panel, go to the "subdomains" option, and check the subdomain there. If you can't do that by whatever reasons, you can do a simple PHP browser (so you can browse the filesystem), and figure out where is it.

Comment: OK, now I'm gettting this error: `open_basedir restriction in effect. File(../../../www/htdocs/w000000/imgs/example.jpg) is not within the allowed path(s)` What does it mean exactly?

Comment: open_basedir is a PHP directive which specifies the permissions that the current directory has. e.g. if open_basedir is `/www/htdocs/w000000` (inside the same directory), then all the files within that directory can only and **only** access files/folders from `w000000` and subdirectories (meaning you can't access `/www/htdocs/`, because it's higher). To fix it, you can disable `open_basedir` or modify it so it allows your script to access the `imgs` folder. All that from your hosting's control panel.